Play a byte[] of audio clips in sequence
I have a collection of Audio data stored as byte[] in an ObservableCollection. I want to iterate through and be able to play them all one after the other in my Maui app. I need the ability to Stop playback midway through as well. The issue with my code below is that all the audio files start playing at the same time over one another and ending as they end. (The player does work fine when sending individual songs, and even able to Stop() as needed)
        foreach (var record in VoiceAudioCollection)
        {
            voicePlayer = new VoicePlayer(record.FileBytes);
            voicePlayer.PlaybackEnded += (sender, args) =>
            {
                record.IsPlaying = false;
                currentlyPlaying = null;
                voicePlayer = null;
                Console.WriteLine($"*** PLAYBACK ENDED *** {record.Id}");
            };
            voicePlayer.Play();
        }

I have the VoicePlayer defined in each of Android and iOS as follows.
iOS:
private AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer player;
public void Play()
{
    isFinishedPlaying = false;
    player.Play();
}

Android:
    private Android.Media.MediaPlayer player;
    public void Play()
    {
        if (!isPlaying)
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            player.Start();
        }
    }

I'm looking for pointers on how to play this list of songs in sequence.

You don't want to loop through playing.  You want to pass play a list of songs to play.  It then saves that list of songs, and plays the next one when the previous one is finished.  player.start() doesn't block waiting for the player to finish, so you're playing them all at once.  MediaPlayer has a callback to tell you when a song is finished, use that to start the next one.

You’re assuming the code pauses while the audio plays.  It doesn’t.  It starts playing then immediately loops to the next item in the list.  You need to start playing the next song when PlaybackEnded fires

Yes, I did assume since it's synchronous programming (vs async/await) that the foreach wouldn't iterate until the Player had finished. I modified the service to take a list of audio clips and iterate through them via the service to accomplish the playback. Thank for the suggestions Gabe and Jason

something like this should work
int ndx = 0;

void PlayNext()
{
  if (ndx > VoiceAudioCollection.Count) return;

  var record = VoiceAudioCollection[ndx];
  voicePlayer = new VoicePlayer(record.FileBytes);
  voicePlayer.PlaybackEnded += (sender, args) =>
  {
     record.IsPlaying = false;
     currentlyPlaying = null;
     voicePlayer = null;
     Console.WriteLine($"*** PLAYBACK ENDED *** {record.Id}");
     ndx++;
     PlayNext();
  };
  voicePlayer.Play();
}


Thank you for this. I didn't think about calling the Play itself back. I ended up passing a List of all the AudioClips to the player service, and iterating via the play and FinishedPlaying inside the service to accomplish sequential playing

Well, according to your reply, as an answer:

I want to iterate through and be able to play them all one after the other in my Maui app......

Passing a List of all the AudioClips to the player service and iterating via the play and FinishedPlaying inside the service to accomplish sequential playing can fix the question.
